# Why do I need to await twice

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm trying to run some IO blocking code, so I'm using `to_thread` to send the function to another thread. I tried several things, but in all cases, I seem to have to `await` the `to_thread` which just returns *another* coroutine (?!) that I then have to `await` again. For some reason this isn't quite clicking.

```py
import asyncio

async def search(keyword_list):
    coroutines = set()
    for index, kw in enumerate(keyword_list):
            coroutines.add(asyncio.to_thread(do_lookup, keyword, index))

    for result in asyncio.as_completed(coroutines):
        outcome, index = await result
        # Do some magic with the outcome and index
        # BUT, this doesn't work because `await result` apparently
        # just returns ANOTHER coroutine!


async def do_lookup(keyword, index):
    # Do long, blocking stuff here
    print(f'running...{keyword} {index}')
    return keyword, index


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(search([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Answer (score 3):

As I was copy/pasting and adapting my code to make a generic example, I discovered the problem here.

`do_lookup` is supposed to a *synchronous* function (because of the usage of `to_thread`), so by defining it `async dev do_lookup` I'm instead defining it as an *asynchronous* function, thereby causing the "double" `await` issue.

Simply redefining `do_lookup` without the `async` keyword did the trick!

Comment: So – lesson learned: if your function doesn't use `await`, don't make it `async` :)

Comment: Definitely! And I was so confused! It's amazing how just looking at it more closely for a copy/paste gave me my lightbulb moment

Comment: The other lesson is that when you CALL an async def function, the object you get is not the result of the function's execution but a coroutine.  The result is the value of the corresponding await expression.